# mask sensitive data in .net core 6

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, ef-core-6.0

I am using .net core 6 Entity framework. I have certain fields like account number, SSN to show only last 4 digits. The response coming from .net api is fed into react form. The data should be masked from .net api.

The current DTO I have is

```
public class BankDetails

    {

        public string? RoutingNumber { get; set; }
        public string? AccountNumber { get; set; }
        [IgnoreField]
        public string DisplayRoutingNumber
        {
            get
            {
                if (RoutingNumber != null && RoutingNumber.Length > 4)
                {
                    return string.Format("*****{0}", RoutingNumber[(RoutingNumber.Length - 4)..]);
                }
                else
                {
                    return RoutingNumber;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

and setting the data

```
BankDetails form = new()

            {
                RoutingNumber = transmissionSettings?.RoutingNumber,
                AccountNumber = transmissionSettings?.AccountNumber,
            };
            if (NoPermission)
            {
                formData.RoutingNumber = form.DisplayRoutingNumber;
            }
```

I am looking for a more generic approach for this scenario. For example having a custom attribute for `[SensitiveField]` in the dto and write the custom logic.

Comment: automapper might help with this.

Comment: Check this 
string pattern = @"(?<=\d{4})\d(?=\d{4})";
return Regex.Replace(RoutingNumber, pattern, "*");

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, you can [custom converters for JSON serialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/converters-how-to?pivots=dotnet-7-0) to achieve it. Please refer to this simple demo:

```
public class SensitiveField : JsonConverter<string>
    {
        public override string? Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
        {
            return reader.GetString();
        }

        public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, string value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
        {
            if (value.Length > 4)
            {
                writer.WriteStringValue("****" + value.Substring(value.Length - 4));
            }
        }
    }
```

Now, if you want make any property show only last 4 digits, You can just add `[JsonConverter(typeof(SensitiveField))]` attribute on it.

**Demo:**

```
public class TestModel
    {
        [JsonConverter(typeof(SensitiveField))]
        public string AccountNumber { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }
```

[image]

I hope it can help you solve this issue.

Comment: What do you mean about `class in injected in controller`? I'm not sure why you need to inject the class into controller, Can you explain in more details?